# Why use (t1-t2)>(1U<<31) instead of pure comparison?

Tags: c++

I get the code from the old project:

```
inline bool timer_timestamp_less(uint32_t t1,uint32_t t2){
        return (t1-t2)>(1U<<31);
}
```

somewhere:

```
 if(!timer_timestamp_less(t1,t2)) ..
```

After a headache, I understand the code is equivalent

```
if(t1>t2)...
```

My predecessor has code while lacking cafe. Or do I think too simple?

Comment: It may be a thought process thing, where they recognized that they were getting the wrong results, and wrote a test for the wrong result, rather than the cause

Comment: You predecessor seems to have tunnel visioned when writing this, I'd say.

Comment: Hopefully, I changed the code, expect nothing wrong with the solution.

Comment: Failure to comment that line of code is, IMHO, inexcusable.

Comment: Playing with timestamp arithmetics?  Be very very careful, especially around the call to timer_timestamp_less().

Answer (score 3):

No your refactoring doesn't recover the same result in all cases: `if(!timer_timestamp_less(t1, t2))` is *nearly* the same as `if(t1 > t2)`.

The original implementation appears to be relying on the well-defined wraparound behaviour for the expression `t1 - t2`, which will inject 1 into the most significant bit for the case where `t2` is greater than `t1`, and neither `t1` nor `t2` have that original bit set to 1. (In the latter case the behaviour is much more complicated.)

For values of `t1` and `t2` in the range [0, 2<sup>31</sup> - 1], the equivalent expression is, in fact, `!(t1 < t2)`. Currently the way you have it, the expressions differ for the case where `t1` and `t2` are equal:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

inline bool timer_timestamp_less_1(uint32_t t1,uint32_t t2){
    return (t1-t2)>(1U<<31);
}

inline bool timer_timestamp_less_2(uint32_t t1,uint32_t t2){
    return (t1 < t2);
}

int main(){
    // Equivalent
    cout << !timer_timestamp_less_1(1, 2) << endl; // 0
    cout << !timer_timestamp_less_2(1, 2) << endl; // 0
    // Not Equivalent
    cout << !timer_timestamp_less_1(-1, 2) << endl; // 0
    cout << !timer_timestamp_less_2(-1, 2) << endl; // 1
}
```

Code: https://ideone.com/yocmS2

Comment: but  cout << (-1 < 2) << endl; //1

Comment: I have a question. Why does `timer_timestamp_less_1` give `0` as result [here](https://ideone.com/qNBIbD) ?

Comment: Is this code a comparison for signed numbers using `unsigned int`?

Comment: I'm using a negative to force a 1 bit into the most significant bit into the unsigned type. This is well-defined behaviour by the standard.

Comment: I mean: if t1,t2 is int, why need cast to uint?
if t1, t2 is uint, so why need 1U<<31, and in this case wrong

Comment: If it's easier for you to stomach, use UINT_MAX in place of my -1.

Comment: There was a difference. So, what is the function of the above function for?
The difference as I have commented before: " if t1, t2 is uint, so why need 1U << 31, and in this case wrong"
This case is more likely to be wrong than to have a different purpose.

Comment: @HoànTrần: Without inspecting all the call sites, any comment on the reason for the function being written that way is pure conjecture.

Comment: t1,t2 is timestamp (seconds since Jan 01 1970. (UTC))
t1: current time
t2: maximum allowable time
if(t1>t2) timeout()..